# Qt setCurrentIndex does not emit currentChanged for invalid ModelIndex

Tags: c++, qt

I have a wizard where the user is only allowed to advance when he has selected an entry from a QListView. To check that, i have connected my method containing the validation logic to the `currentChanged` signal, but the signal is not emitted if the selected Index is invalid:

```
// It's connected like this
connect(connectionsListView->selectionModel(), 
        SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
        this, SLOT(connectionSelected(QModelIndex)));

// Does not emit for empty ListModel
connectionsListView->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex
    (connectionListModel->index(0, 0), QItemSelectionModel::SelectCurrent);

// Does not emit whatsoever
connectionsListView->selectionModel()->clear();

// Valid selections are delegated to my validation logic and handled correctly
```

Any ideas why this happens and what i can do to fix that? Currently i have a second signal that i emit in my code on occasions where the index could be invalid, but i would prefer Qt simply emitting the signal if the index is invalid.

Comment: If some items are not allowed to be selected by user, you can those items using Qt::ItemIsSelectable flag.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `currentChanged` signal does not get emitted when the model is empty (since there is nothing that has changed). For a non-empty model, I wrote an [MCVE here](http://pastebin.com/3RgGdkic), the signal gets emitted for me in both operations as expected (Qt 5.7 here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line can't emit because the index didn't change: it was invalid, and still is invalid, since the model is empty. There is an invariant: on an empty model, the selection index is invalid. Thus for as long as the model is empty, you should never expect the `currentChanged` signal to be emitted.

The second line doesn't emit for the same reason: the index still is invalid.

You might need to create a test case that reproduces the issue: you need to do something that changes the value returned by `currentIndex` yet doesn't fire the signal. Note that resetting the selection model will not fire the signal. You could treat as a bug perhaps.

Comment: The fact that no signal is emitted if the index was invalid before and after selection is very helpful. The second case should work however, i will have to check that tomorrow. Thank you!